# Swaping two elements in a list shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
lis = [12,45,15,67,89]
```

I want to swap 12 and 89 such that the list should look

```
lis = [89,45,15,67,12]
```

When I do it this way

```
lis[0], lis[lis.index(89)] = lis[lis.index(89)], lis[0]
```

Nothing is changed

```
lis = [12,45,15,67,89]
```

But when I do it this way

```
lis5[0], lis5[4] = lis5[4], lis5[0]
```

It works perfect

```
lis = [89,45,15,67,12]
```

So why it isn't working the first way? PS-The whole reason I want to do the first way is because I want to find the max element in a list and then swap it with the first element of the list.

Something like:

```
max1 = max(lis)
lis[0], lis[lis.index(max1)] = lis[lis.index(max1)], lis[0]
```

Comment: `>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
`>>> ix = x.index(max(x))`
`>>> v = x[0]`
`>>> x[0], x[ix] = max(x), v`
`>>> x`
`[4, 2, 3, 1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, `lis.index(max1)` in left/right sides are evaluated at different times; then evaluated to different values (`0` for the left side, `4` for the right side).

---

```
a, b = b, a
```

Above statement:

- creates `(b, a)` tuple
- unpacks the above tuple to `a` and `b`

  - a = old-value-of-b
  - b = old-value-of-a

---

```
lis[0], lis[lis.index(89)] = lis[lis.index(89)], lis[0]
```

becomes

```
lis[0], lis[lis.index(89)] = lis[4], lis[0]
```

=>

```
lis[0], lis[lis.index(89)] = 89, 0
```

=>

```
lis[0] = 89
lis[lis.index(89)] = 0
```

=>

```
lis[0] = 89
lis[0] = 0    # NOTE lis.index(89) == 0  at this point
```

So `lis[0]` assigned 89, then assigned original value 0 back. => (only the first element changed, and re-assigned original value)

---

To avoid this problem, assign the index before the swap statement:

```
idx = lis.index(89)
lis[0], lis[idx] = lis[idx], lis[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend the accepted answer,
You can store using dict.

```
lis = [12,45,15,67,89]
new_list = []


dict = {k:v for (k,v) in enumerate(lis)}

    
dict[0], dict[4] = dict[4], dict[0]
    
for i in range(len(lis)):
    new_list.append(dict[i])
   
print(new_list)
```

And the way you were trying,

```
lis = [12,45,15,67,89]

lis[lis.index(89)], lis[0] = lis[0], lis[lis.index(89)]

print(lis)
```

both produces,

```
[89, 45, 15, 67, 12]

[Program finished]
```

Alternatively, for max values,

```
lis = [12,45,15,67,89]
max_index = lis.index(max(lis))
lis[0], lis[max_index] = lis[max_index], lis[0]
print(lis)
```